# Calculate the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3n+2}-\frac{1}{3n+3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Calculate the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3n+2}-\frac{1}{3n+3}$.

There was this hint to use Mittag-Leffler decomposition of $\frac{pi}{a}ctg{\frac{\pi b}{a}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{na+b}-\frac{1}{na+{a-b}})$. So I found this useful to calulate another sum, namely: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3n+1}-\frac{1}{3n+2}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}$. But I can't see how it can be used to the question related sum. Any other approach is welcome.

Comment: One method: calculate a closed form for $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (x^{3n+2}-x^{3n+3}),$$ then calculate $f'(1)$.

Comment: We can write $\frac{1}{3n+2}=\int_0^1 t^{3n+1} dt$, … By summing, we obtain geometric sums Under the integral.

Comment: See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1588751p9839105

Comment: @GregMartin: I think you must mean $\int f$, not $f'$.

Comment: @TonyK aha, yes of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can rewrite the summation as an integral:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3n+2}-\frac{1}{3n+3} = \int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{3n+1}-x^{3n+2}\:dx$$

$$= \int_0^1\frac{x}{1-x^3}-\frac{x^2}{1-x^3}\:dx = \int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x+x^2}\:dx$$

Then to calculate the integral, add and subtract $\frac{1}{2}$ in the numerator

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}}{1+x+x^2}\:dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{1+2x}{1+x+x^2}\:dx - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}+\left(\frac{1}{2}+x\right)^2}\:dx$$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\log(1+x+x^2)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+2x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\Biggr|_0^1 = \log\sqrt{3} - \frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$S= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int (x^{3n+1}-x^{3n+2})dx= \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [x(x^3)^n-x^2(x^3)^{n}] dx=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x}{1+x+x^2} dx=\frac{\ln 3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{18}.$$
Here we have used integral representation of $\frac{1}{t}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{t-1}dx$
and sum if iGP.

Comment: The sum is missing after the second equality

Comment: Thanks I have edited it now.